# Postgresql: How to get null values when using WHERE col NOT LIKE "foo"?

Tags: postgresql

When using `WHERE` clause with `NOT LIKE` on `my_text_column`, `null` values are skipped.

Why and how to get it ?

```
SELECT count(id) FROM public.mytable;
 count 
-------
    91
SELECT count(id) FROM public.mytable WHERE my_text_column LIKE 'foo';
 count 
-------
    59
SELECT count(id) FROM public.mytable WHERE my_text_column NOT LIKE 'foo';
 count 
-------
     0
```

Comment: Try `SELECT count(id) FROM public.mytable WHERE my_text_column NOT LIKE 'foo' OR my_text_column  IS NULL ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL standard says this about NULL in Framework, 4.4.2:

> [...] the null value is neither equal to any other value nor not equal to any other value – it is *unknown* whether or not it is equal to any given value [...]

In 4.4.3.3 it says:

> A value of the *Boolean* data type is either *true* or *false*. The truth value of *unknown* is sometimes represented by the null value.

In its quirky way, it says that comparing something to the NULL values will result in NULL. Think of it this way: it is unknown if an unknown string is like `foo`.

There are several ways to get what you want:

1. Use `coalesce`:

   ```
   WHERE coalesce(my_text_column, 'foo') LIKE 'foo%'
   ```
2. Use an `OR`:

   ```
   WHERE my_text_column LIKE 'foo%' OR my_text_column IS NULL
   ```
3. use `UNION ALL`:

   ```
   SELECT count(id)
   FROM (SELECT id FROM public.mytable
         WHERE my_text_column LIKE 'foo%'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id FROM public.mytable
         WHERE my_text_column IS NULL) AS subq;
   ```

Queries like that make indexing complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT count(*) FROM public.mytable 
WHERE my_text_colum not LIKE 'foo' or my_text_colum is null;
```

From [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

> If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the
> pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like
> the **equals** operator.

So `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl3 WHERE txt <> 'foo' or txt is null;` also works.